# Keep having an error when using static array which is not initialized

Tags: c

I am using 16bit microcontroller which uses gcc4.5 compiler, 32kbyte flash/1kbyte ram. compiling is fine without error, memory is reaching to it's limit but it has some vacancy on both flash/ram and works just fine

However, when i define static array without initialization it causes system to die. I cannot use debugger to watch what's going on inside my system.

I didn't even use the array other than define it. so I assume compiler should skip below code but it kept making a problem.

```
typedef enum
{
    PTC_VOLT_ERROR = 0,
    PTC_LINE_ERROR,
    PTC_ERROR,  
    PTC_PCB1TEMP_ERROR,
    PTC_PCB2TEMP_ERROR, 
    PTC_COMM_ERROR,
    PTC_SELF_DIAG_ERROR,
    PTC_PCB1TEMPSSR_ERROR,
    PTC_PCB2TEMPSSR_ERROR,
    NUM_OF_PTC_ERROR_TYPE
}PtcErrorTypeInfo_t;
(...)
static INT8U preErrorInfo[NUM_OF_PTC_ERROR_TYPE]; // This cause system to die
//static INT8U preErrorInfo[NUM_OF_PTC_ERROR_TYPE]={0,}; // This is ok
```

Then I tried with non-static global arry and found it was working well.

```
INT8U preErrorInfo[NUM_OF_PTC_ERROR_TYPE]; // This is ok
static INT8U preErrorInfo[2]; // This is also ok


static INT8U preErrorInfo[9]; // This is not working
static INT8U preErrorInfo[2]; // This is working
```

I want to know what could make my system down?

**→→→ It turned out that it had something to do with overflow and trap error.**

first>> when I compile without static, in the map file

```
 .data.g_PtcProtectionState
                0x0000007e        0x2 obj/EcuProtectCTR.o
                0x0000007e                _g_PtcProtectionState
 .data.preErrorInfo
                0x00000080        0x9 obj/EcuProtectCTR.o
 .data.u1_ErrorDeterTmr
                0x00000089        0x1 obj/EcuProtectCTR.o
 .data.pendingCalibOn
                0x0000008a        0x6 obj/EcuSsrInputCTR.o
                0x0000008a                _pendingCalibOn

(...)
 .bss.g_u4_ErrorCntrInfo
                0x00000144        0x4 obj/EcuProtectCTR.o
 **.bss.g_u1_TmrInt
                0x00000148        0x1 obj/SchM.o
                0x00000148                _g_u1_TmrInt**
 .bss.u1_ElapsedTime
                0x00000149        0x1 obj/SchM.o
```

it makes preErrorInfo[9] array seats in the data area.

second>> if i compile with 'static'

```
 .bss.g_u4_ErrorCntrInfo
                0x0000013c        0x4 obj/EcuProtectCTR.o
 .bss.preErrorInfo
                0x00000140        0x9 obj/EcuProtectCTR.o
 .bss.g_u1_TmrInt
                0x00000149        0x1 obj/SchM.o
                0x00000149                _g_u1_TmrInt
```

preErrorInfo arry nicely seats on bss area. However, there is a variable 'g_u1_TmrInt' which keeps causing a problem. this timer-interrupt geard variable keeps making an overflow.

since 'static preErrorInfo array' will seat right above 'g_u1_TmrInt' somehow it could be messed up with 'static preErrorInfo array' when overflowing.

**But I wonder why it didn't cause a problem when it comes to a case 'first>>' which has a 'g_u4_ErrorCntrInfo' 4byte array seated right above 'g_u1_TmrInt' and it would surely make the same overflow error.**

※ when I change 'g_u1_TmrInt' type to 16bit(no-overflow and no error), it would look like this and work like charm.

```
 .bss.preErrorInfo
                0x00000140        0x9 obj/EcuProtectCTR.o
 *fill*         0x00000149        0x1 
 .bss.g_u1_TmrInt
                0x0000014a        0x2 obj/SchM.o
                0x0000014a                _g_u1_TmrInt
 .bss.u1_ElapsedTime
                0x0000014c        0x2 obj/SchM.o
 .bss.SchConfig
```

Comment: The working/not working code should behave identically. A static array is guaranteed to be initialized to all-zeros by the C standard, so if you explicitly initialize it or not shouldn't make a difference. Maybe time to look at the generated code.

Comment: This chip doesn't support code-generation. So everything is coded by hand. this is why I cannot belive that a non-initialized static array is identical to an initialized static arry. it apparently making a problem...

Comment: @woehswe "This chip doesn't support code-generation." What do you mean by that? There is some compiled code being generated by the compiler.

Comment: Look at memory map of the linked program (you may need to add command line switch to get it). Does it look ok? How is it different between static and non-static global array?

Comment: Only difference it would make is zero initialsed array will be part of bss memory region. Otherwise, should not be a problem. As it is a very specific problem and you don't have a debugger, What happens when you say "System dies"? And is it immediately at startup or after some time - fixed or random.

Comment: It appears you are saying that `static INT8U preErrorInfo[2];` works but `static INT8U preErrorInfo[9];` does not.

Comment: [Initialized] -->  .data.preErrorInfo 0x00000080        0x9 obj/EcuProtectCTR.o                                           [UnInitialized] -->  .bss.preErrorInfo
                0x00000140        0x9 obj/EcuProtectCTR.o

Comment: Perhaps there is something else you are changing too.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thanks. I got it working. it turned out that it has something to do with overflow.

Comment: I recommend deleting the question since the problem is now diagnosed as a "writing out of bounds elsewhere", which is not something you can make into a succinct SO question.